Where is this version upgrade dialog box coming from? Why doesn't it work?
On Ubuntu Jammy I keep seeing the following dialog box:

I'm currently running 22.04.4:
If I click "Yes, Upgrade Now", the dialog closes but nothing seems to happen. Soon enough I'll see the dialog appear again.
What's going on? Where is this dialogue coming from? Why does it not seem to trigger any process when I click "Yes"?

Open a terminal. Run sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade. Copy the complete output of both. Paste both into your question above.

Do NOT upgrade. The upgrade path is buggy and is rendering many people's systems unbootable. Ubuntu 22.04 will be supported until 2027, so there is no rush to upgrade. Also, you can fresh install 24.04 if you really want to upgrade
